# Set the html fontsize in `pygmentize`, the command line tool of `pygments`

Tags: python, html, command-line, pygments, pygmentize

I'm trying to convert a python file into an html file using `pygments` via the command line tool `pygmentize` with the following command:

```
pygmentize -f html -O full -O linenos=1 out_file.html in_file.py
```

Unfortunately, the default fontsize is too small and I don't know how to increase it. Using `-O fontsize=16` does not rise an error, but has no effect either.

Additionally, I tried an ugly patch by inserting `html *{font-size: 1.05em !important;}` into the css part of the html document but that compromises the line numbering layout.

I am able to call 'pygments' via a python terminal, but don't know how one would implement the command line into python code

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed the problem by using the following python code:

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.formatters import get_formatter_by_name

lexer = get_lexer_by_name('python')
formatter = get_formatter_by_name('html', linenos='inline', full=1)

with open("conver_me.py", 'r') as f_in:
    code = "".join(f_in.readlines())

with open("output.html", 'w') as f_out:
    highlight(code, lexer, formatter, f_out)
```

I then added the line

```
html *{font-size: 1.05em !important;}
```

into the css part of the html document and adapted the table padding

```
span.lineno { background-color: #f0f0f0; padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px; }
```

Comment: Is there really no way to "Set the fontsize in `pygmentize`, the command line tool of `pygments`" directly?